# Jenkins Pipeline procedure

Tags: jenkins

When I check in my gitlab code from dev, it triggers Jenkins to build this dev branch and deploy the application on the staging server 1. I have selenium automated testing to run against this deployed application (eg Test UI & API etc).

Question:
If the test all passes, Jenkins should deploy a production code on server 2. Can and should Jenkins make a merge request from dev to master in order to do the build?

Answer (score 0):

Theese are possible.

1.You need conditional steps in jenkins.
2.You need conditional steps again and you must use git commands.(git commit,git push etc.)